# Can I disable the System() command in R?

Tags: r, security

I have a server with Microsoft R Open installed on it. Is it possible for me to restrict use of the `System()` command so that users are unable to call shell commands from within R?

If this is not possible, is that for a reason specific to Microsoft R Open, or is what I’m asking for fundamentally impossible with any R implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a security perspective I think that the best practice is to make a user account that only has the privileges you want (i.e. not an admin, no inappropriate read/write, etc) then run R as that user.

The clever suggestions in the comments to mask the function would be a hotfix, but would do little to deter any knowledgeable person from taking advantage. OTOH perhaps you could combine both.

Here is a trivial example of how a "hacker" could defeat function masking:

```
system <- function(x) {print("I am masked!")}
system()
[1] "I am masked!"
rm(system); print("Take off the mask!")
[1] "Take off the mask!"
system() # not masked now
Error in system() : argument "command" is missing, with no default
```

Someone in the comments asked about non-privileged commands like `ls`. If you also want to disable non-privileged commands like `ls` I would probably take the security/user -based approach and then either

1. Restrict folder access to a designated sandbox for R data/code (kind of like they do on Kaggle) and/or
2. Ask on http://serverfault.com (a sister Stack Exchange site) how to also restrict non-privileged commands (update - I have gone ahead and asked that question and it's awaiting replies)

Update:

To illustrate how simply masking `rm` isn't a solution either:

```
system <- function(x) {print("I am masked!")}
system("cmd.exe")
rm(system); print("Take off the mask!")
system("cmd.exe")
rm <- function(x){print("Now I masked rm")}
remove(rm)
rm(system)
system("cmd.exe")
```

Comment: But, in this case I could also mask the rm function.

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil This is not a solution because 1. you only see this patch in hindsight and it's specific to the exploit that's already been used 2. it's easily defeated. For example: `rm <- function(x){print("Now I masked rm")};remove(rm);rm(system);system("cmd.exe")`. I have updated my answer to reflect this, thank you.